# problem with registering new users Dspace 6.3

Tags: registration, dspace

Good day! At the Medical University of Karaganda, we want to use Dspace 6.3, because we liked your product. But we have a problem with registering new users. We want our repository to be used throughout Kazakhstan. According to the instructions in dspace.cfg, we have made changes, but registration for new users does not work. about gmail: Starting from May 30, 2022, Google no longer supports third-party apps and devices.

about gmail: Starting from May 30, 2022, Google no longer supports third-party apps and devices.

I am sending part of the code: for example

Email settings

SMTP mail server (allows DSpace to send email notifications)
mail.server = mail.kgmu.kz

SMTP mail server authentication username and password (if required)
mail.server.username = ABCD@kgmu.kz
mail.server.password = ABCDF

SMTP mail server alternate port (defaults to 25)
mail.server.port = 25

Thank you in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first go to your google account settings.

Then you have to enable two factor authentication.

Then go to app passwords.

Give some random name.

Generate a 16 letter password.

Store it somewhere safely.

Then enter that password in:

mail.server.password field in dspace.cfg file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).